# Create a struct in C Preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Right now, I am writing a small project in C to test out some serialization techniques.
One way that I am doing this is through the use of unions. Something that I would like to try is creating a union in the C preprocessor that holds a user-defined structure. For example, something like this:

```
#define create_union(name_of_structure, type_of_structure) \ 
                                                           \
typedef union name_of_structure {                          \                                 
      typeof(type_of_structure) structure;                 \                        
      char buffer_that_holds_structure[sizeof(type_of_structure)]; \
} name_of_structure;

/* Usage */
struct my_data {
      int id;
      int other_value;
};

create_union(my_data_t, struct my_data);
/* Data type my_data_t (union my_data_t) now exists */
```

First of all, is this feasible? If it is, how would I go about doing this? If not, is there an alternative method I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: `typeof(type_of_structure)` -> `type_of_structure`? Also, have you compiled this? Was there an error? If not, did you check with `-pedantic -Wall` flags to be sure?

Comment: It compiles with -Wall and -pedantic. The typeof() is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and your code is very close to correct.

I'd drop the semicolon at the end of the macro definition.  I'd also drop the use of `typeof`; it's not portable and it's not needed unless you want to use an expression, rather than a type name, as the first argument to `create_union`.

Here's how I'd probably define it.  (I don't bother with typedefs for struct or union types; I just use the name `struct foo` or `union foo` unless the type is intended to be completely opaque.  Feel free to use the typedef if you prefer.) (I've also used `unsigned char` rather than `char`, since that's how object representations are defined.)

```
#define CREATE_UNION(new_type, existing_type) \
union new_type {                              \
      existing_type obj;                      \
      unsigned char rep[sizeof(existing_type)]; \
}
```

And you can then do:

```
CREATE_UNION(int_wrapper, int);
int_wrapper foo;
```

Note that what you're defining is a **union**, not a **structure**.